# Should I acquire a lock on Properties first before looping setProperety?

Tags: java, performance, properties, thread-safety, synchronized

The java class [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is a thread-safe Class as per it's documentation:

> This class is thread-safe: multiple threads can share a single Properties object without the need for external synchronization.

Because of that reason, I have the habit of maintaining my Properties in a `HashMap` implementation of `Map`, which is not thread-safe, but much more lightweight. More specifically, implementing thread-safety requires additional locking mechanisms, which will have an impact on performance. I can easily avoid this by simply segregating my property initialization in a static class initializer, which will guarantee it's completion before I use any get calls in instance methods of the same class.

This is so far was just a narrative that leads me to the actual question. Eventually I need to revert to API's that can only accept 'Properties' as a Parameter, an example being [`DriverManager.getConnection(String,Properties)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-). I need to convert my `Map` into `Properties`.

So a first attempt would look like something like this:

```
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  this.propertyMap.forEach((k,v)->{properties.setProperty(k, v);});
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
```

Obvious problem, or maybe not so obvious as I avoided using an actual for-loop, is that I use a repeated call to `Properties.setProperty`. If `Properties` is truly thread safe, then that must mean that each call to `setProperty` is synchronized and has individual lock/unlock mechanisms added to it.

*Would it not be better in such a case that I manually lock the entire `Properties` instance first as in code below?*

```
Connection connection;
Properties properties = new Properties();
synchronized (properties) {
  // Properties is implemented as thread-safe. As it adds
  // additional thread locking, it's use is localized to just
  // here to avoid consequential performance issues. We will
  // do a last minute conversion from Map to Properties right here.
  this.propertyMap.forEach((k,v)->{properties.setProperty(k, v);});
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
}
```

One issue I was possibly expecting is that both manual lock on properties, and the individual calls to `setProperties` might have caused a deadlock, but it seems to run fine.

Comment: There's no point synchronizing on a local instance of `Properties`. I would consider locking on the `ProperyMap`, but then each time you wanted update the map, you'd need to also be locking on it to prevent possible mutation between threads

Comment: locks are reentrant. also uncontended synchronizations are fast. so this may not be worth bothering about.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I avoid concurrent mutation of the `Map` instance by following convention rather than locking. This is what I tried to explain in the section leading up to my actual question. But why is there no point in synchronizing a local instance of `Properties`?

Comment: @JoD. Because you created a local instance of it.  If two threads are running your code, both will have different instances of a `Properties` object, so both will execute the code in the `synchronized` block at the same time, from my perspective, it's just a waste of time/resources

Comment: @NathanHughes, I like your response. This is certainly something I will consider in my implementations (uncontested synchronizations). So maybe this is now more a question out of curiosity - does the presented code has it's intended effect: "avoiding the repeated locking"?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, my intention was not to achieve locking, but actually to avoid locking as part of this statement: `this.propertyMap.forEach((k,v)->{properties.setProperty(k, v);});`

Comment: I smell premature optimization.  Have you measured this alleged impact on performance?

Comment: @JoD. Ahh, my confusion

Comment: I don't even see the point of your *loop.* There are only two property *keys* being set: `"0"` and `"1"`, and the values respectively are `size-2` and `size-1`, or the other way round, depending on whether `size` is even or odd. You could express this in two lines of code.

Comment: Any reason for not using `properties.putAll(propertyMap);`? That will acquire the lock exactly one time…

Comment: @EJP The point of the loop was not to measure increasing search-time or grow time. The intention was to measure only the synchronization overhead. In real life this would have been pointless, but not for the purpose of the benchmark. Even so, to be able to have comparable tests with `putAll(m)`, I have abandoned the method and am now putting a new key every single time.

Comment: @Holger - good point, I missed that one. Changed my whole test approach to be able to have comparable tests with `putAll`. With all the effort being done, I have combined your input with the tests I have done so far in a new answer. Did not make sense to continue to evolve the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I have made invalid conclusions based on improper benchmarking. Even though I have attempted some type of warm-up, It was never really enough.

Only by the third iteration (once the iteration was added), which was using a full dataset, did the measurements level off, and came within range of each other so they could be called same with insignificant differences.

## Amended Conclusion

Conclusion is now that the methods are really pretty much irrelevant. I can still see that `HashMap` is overall a bit better performing than `Properties` but not enough to make me choose performance over readability.

As per the suggestion of @Holger, I would propose to just use the `Properties.putAll(other)` method. It is fast, and performs about as well as the others.

However, if you do use this in a multithreaded environment, I would suggest using `HashMap`, and carefully consider concurrent access. Usually that is easily accomplishable without the need of overly locking/synchronize.

I think that was a good lesson learned.

Below are a bit more normalized measurements. I cheated a little by eyeballing and picking a sample without outliers instead of trying to average/median over multiple samples. Just for avoiding the complexity (and additional work) of doing so, or having to acquire an external tool.

```
+----------------------------------+----------+--------+
|               Name               | Unlocked | Locked |
+----------------------------------+----------+--------+
| putAll->Properties               | 1,644    | 1,429  |
| forEach->setProperty->Properties | 1,474    | 1,740  |
| stream->setProperty->Properties  | 1,484    | 1,735  |
| loop->setProperty->Properties    | 2,022    | 1,606  |
| forEach->put->Properties         | 1,590    | 1,411  |
| stream->put->Properties          | 1,538    | 1,514  |
| loop->put->Properties            | 1,380    | 1,666  |
| putAll->Map                      | 1,380    | 509    |
| forEach->put->Map                | 935      | 915    |
| stream->put->Map                 | 927      | 888    |
| loop->put->Map                   | 880      | 1,015  |
+----------------------------------+----------+--------+
```

## Methodology

The methods for testing, is in the same order as in the table above, with `p` being a `Properties` and `m` a `Map` as a target:

```
  p.putAll(SOURCEMAP);
  SOURCEMAP.forEach(p::setProperty);
  SOURCEMAP.entrySet().stream().forEach((e)->{p.setProperty(e.getKey(), e.getValue());});
  for (Map.Entry<String,String> e:SOURCEMAP.entrySet()) p.setProperty(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
  SOURCEMAP.forEach(p::put);
  SOURCEMAP.entrySet().stream().forEach((e)->{p.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());});
  for (Map.Entry<String,String> e:SOURCEMAP.entrySet()) p.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
  m.putAll(SOURCEMAP);
  SOURCEMAP.forEach(m::put);
  SOURCEMAP.entrySet().stream().forEach((e)->{m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());});
  for (Map.Entry<String,String> e:SOURCEMAP.entrySet()) m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

The full source code is available at GitHub: http://github.com/jdesmet/properties-benchmarking.