# Why synchronized access to a Map adds a considerable amount of overhead

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, synchronized

This code is the base (fastest):

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (E e:source) map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

This code is slower (x2):

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
synchronized(map) {
  for (E e:source) map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```

This code is worse (x20):

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
synchronized(map) {
  source.forEach(map::put);
}
```

For more detailed measurements taken, [see a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35248433/744133) of mine. For the full source code, see [GitHub repository](http://github.com/jdesmet/properties-benchmarking).

Why those big discrepancies? If a `HashMap` is truly lightweight and not thread-safe (no `synchronized`), then overhead should have been negligible. Besides locks are supposed to be reentrant.

When using `Properties`, I actually get the reverse effect, as I would have expected: I save time by acquiring a single lock beforehand (before the loop starts).

Can some-one explain those discrepancies?

Note that I am using following JVM option: `-Xms4g`

UPDATE: a good article on benchmarking - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-benchmark1/

Comment: What does `HashMap`'s being lightweight have to do with the fact that *you* are adding synchronization on top of it?

Comment: Plus, it's clear you aren't using standard Java benchmarking practices.  Your results are invalid for all the usual reasons.

Comment: @chrylis - well I can look into those benchmarking practices. But as to your first question, one has indeed nothing to do with the other, except in the way I make a case: why is it that the synchronized added a disproportional amount of overhead.

Comment: How do you judge the amount to be disproportional? The "overhead" for `Properties` is so small because it already obtains a lock internally (meaning you are already paying the synchronization cost when using that class, as opposed to the lightweight HashMap).

Comment: @Thilo I attempted to judge by using my benchmarking metrics. Also I did *not* state that "overhead for properties was small". I actually significantly improved performance by first locking Properties. However this is not part of my question, and in effect was explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35248433/744133).

Comment: Also, how meaningful is this test if you only have a single thread? If there is no multi-threading, you don't need the lock at all. And a lock is costly.

Comment: @Thilo - as you can notice in my [other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35248433/744133), I actually significantly gained performance by first locking `Properties` (not `Map`). I understand the concept of non locking collections, unfortunately `Properties` is not part of it. It is also not the point of this question to establish whether or not it is meaningful to do so. Sample code is more often than not meaningful, you will understand.

Comment: @JoD. you _really, really, really_ have to get your benchmarking right before you can make any judgements about performance.  If you're not benchmarking correctly, you can find A is faster than B when B is actually going to be twice as fast as A.  You _cannot_ make judgements like the ones you're trying to make without getting your benchmarking technique right first.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I was taking into account several pitfall issues with benchmarking, and I am researching and testing further how certain options might affect performance. However if a certain JVM option affects a certain method of coding, then this adds a valid answer to my problem. For example if GC seems to affect one method more over another, then that is an issue that need to be understood. I will add more sampling to my test cases so I can offset for code JIT and/or GC activity during one method and not another.

Comment: @chryslis - if you make your comment on standard benchmarking practices an actual Answer, and you provide good references to such practices, then I will accept this as the answer. You are right, I only accounted for warmup in a single smaller cycle, but running a 3rd time with a full cycle,  I saw the amount of resources used, and the total run time still significantly reduce. Now my measurements are about equal for any of the methods.

Comment: possible reason -- [escape analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis). In your 2nd example, it's apparent that the map is a local object, therefore the locking can be omitted. The 3rd example is far more difficult because it's unclear what `forEach()` would do

Answer (score 2):

> If a HashMap is truly lightweight and not thread-safe (no `synchronized`), then overhead should have been negligible.

That's a complete *non-sequitur.* The more lightweight the operation inside the `synchronized` block, the higher the relative overhead of synchronization.

> Besides locks are supposed to be reentrant.

They are. So? There is no re-entrancy here.

Comment: Re: Re-entrancy: That works in your favour for the Properties case. There you can take out a lock up front and hold on to it. That will make it much faster to "acquire" the same lock over and over again in the loop (because you are just re-entering). But it gives you nothing in the case of a HashMap (because HashMap does not lock anything).

Comment: @EJP - Then why is it that I have observed that `Properties` with an explicit lock  (not just implicit by API design) will actually run faster than it's `HashMap` cousin with the same explicit lock. Note that I always take care of acquiring the lock outside the iteration, not as part of the iteration. By that I am not convinced at all that the explicit synchronization is at the root cause.

Comment: @JoD. I have no idea. I haven't read your other question and I don't propose to. I'm answering this one.

Comment: @JoD. You haven't observed that. You haven't accounted for all of the microbenchmark issues such as JIT, GC, and just plain jitter.

Comment: @chrylis as the other comment to LouisWasserman , I will offset for the superimposed jitter by sampling more.

Comment: @chrylis as the other comment to LouisWasserman , I will offset for the superimposed jitter by sampling more. Also I argue that I should not just discount the effect of JIT/GC and should in effect be part of the measurements (with sufficient sampling taken). Hence I would not just simply turn off GC (besides - doing so might even have more nefast effects as I eat up swats of memory to accomplish my tests).

Comment: @JoD. There is no difference for the JIT between `synchronized(obj)` and `synchronized` on a method (the main difference is the number of bytes in the method which can effect inlining)

Comment: @JoD.I suggest you look at using JMH for your benchmarks as you likely to find your result will be different.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You and chrysalis were right. The problem is basically my benchmarking methods. My simple warm-up was basically not enough. It is interesting to see now how measurements leveled off and close to each other, method almost irrelevant. Overall though, I can see that `HashMap` is *somewhat*, but not significantly faster than `Properties`.

Comment: @JoD. HashMap and Hashtable size themselves differently and you can get different result for different size of entries.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - yep I considered that, and in one version of my test I avoided the growth by constantly only updating (`.put()`) the same two entries in the properties. However - that methodology cannot be used with the `.putAll(...)` method, I cannot provide a 'set' with multiple times the same entries duplicated as a parameter. Maybe I do those tests separately again without the `.putAll(...)` just for curiosity sake. Also I cannot pre-size `Properties()`, like I can do with a `HashMap`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102819/discussion-between-jod-and-peter-lawrey).